# lodash paths with numbers

Tags: javascript, lodash

`_.set()` seems to be behaving strangely with paths that contain numbers

```
> _.set({}, [2], 1)
{ '2': 1 }
```

This seems reasonable. However:

```
> _.set({}, [2,2], 1)
{ '2': [ , , 1 ] }
```

I understand that the second path part is considered to be an array index. If I use strings:

```
> _.set({}, ["2","2"], 1)
{ '2': [ , , 1 ] }
```

I was expecting

```
{ '2': { '2' : 1} }
```

Is there anyway around this behaviour, other than checking that your path doesn't contain numerish field names?

EDIT: Solution:

```
_.setWith({}, [2, 2], 1, Object)
{ '2': { '2': 1 } }
```

Comment: Why Don't you use quotes in the second? Or stringify the variable before inserting into the function?

Comment: @Randy Sorry, I fixed the examples in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument is not an array index. It is an object path. Object path cannot be an array with two values.

For example on using it correct:

```
_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
```

If your expected result was an object with a sub-path, you can use this:

```
_.setWith(object, '[0][1]', 'a', Object);

// => { '0': { '1': 'a' } }
```